# jquery $("#someID").width(Variable + 'px') worked, now does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Mostly I've worked with php, but decided to learn javascript and jquery. Wrote this script for a wordpress theme. It was working fine then, all of a sudden, just did not respond -- it seems the variables are not being recognized. As I'm new to js and jquery it's probably my bad, but it seems client side scripting is too unstable -- and don't get why its so popular. Here's the script:

```
var $j = jQuery;


$j(function(){

 var curhthMB = $j("#block_main").outerheight();
 /* if(curhthMB < 350) {
   hthMB = 350; }
 else {
   hthMB = curhthMB; } */  

 var widSBL = $j("#block_left").outerWidth();
 var mleft = widSBL;
 var mwidth = 890 - widSBL;

 $j("#block_left").height(curhthMB+'px');
 $j("#block_right").height(curhthMB+'px');

 $j("#block_main").css('left', mleft+'px');
 $j("#block_main").width(mwidth+'px');

 if(widSBL < 10) {
   $j("#block_left").css('border', 'none');
   $j("#block_main").css('margin', '0 20px 0 10px'); }

});
```

Comment: any error in the browser console

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle so we can inspect what the error is?

Comment: As I'm new to js did not even know about jsfiddle. But thank you, will use it in future. As this is for wordpress there are quite a few built in function that generate the content so would actually have to rewrite the html to test in jsfiddle, but will try sometime. Thank you very much for sharing knowledge of jsfiddle

Comment: Solved the problem, it was that I did not capitalize the H in outerHeight -- a dumb newbie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using css more!

Try this

```
$('#someid').css('width',variable+'px')
```

And client-side scripting is the future!! How will you impress with your PHP skills if you can't present it! ;)

Comment: I was just going to suggest the same

Comment: Do you mean I should use css instead of js? This script is meant to change the content blocks dependent on what widgets are added. Not sure css can do that. However, if you mean I should use the .css action as you show above I will definitely try this way. And thank you for sharing. Also, have been thinking of breaking it up into smaller functions, perhaps it will deliver better.

Comment: Yes, have been reading that js is the future, but just don't like all the dependency on browser. Not sure what you mean by presenting php skills. There is nothing js does that can't be done in php, and though there is a lot of hype about js don't think php is going anywhere soon (if node.js & mongoDB ever seriously replace the Lamp stack, then i will worry) -- but as js is a popular skill I will develop a better knowledge. Thank you for your help.

Comment: ok, solved it, my dumb newbie error -- needed to capitalize the H in outerHeight().

Answer (score 0):

```
var $j = jQuery;

$j(function(){

 var curhthMB = $j("#block_main").outerheight();
 /* if(curhthMB < 350) {
   hthMB = 350; }
 else {
   hthMB = curhthMB; } */  

 var widSBL = $j("#block_left").outerWidth();
 var mleft = widSBL;
 var mwidth = 890 - widSBL;

 $j("#block_left").css('height', curhthMB+'px');
 $j("#block_right").css('height', curhthMB+'px');

 $j("#block_main").css('left', mleft+'px');
 $j("#block_main").css('width', mwidth+'px');

 if(widSBL < 10) {
   $j("#block_left").css('border', 'none');
   $j("#block_main").css('margin', '0 20px 0 10px'); }

});
```

Comment: Code without an explanation is almost always useless. Please explain the problem and why your answer solves it.

Comment: I did explain it at top of page. It this code got reposted I'm sorry. This is my first post so not sure why the code got posted twice.

Comment: To explain again: this code was working fine then just stopped working. It adjusts content containers for a wordpress theme dependent on widgets added, or removed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Solved it, was that I did not write outerHeight correctly -- did not capitalize the H -- newbie mistake.